# How / Where to declare a static function twice in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two classes in Symfony:

```
<?php
namespace App\MiniEntities;

class Address {
    // ...

    static function load(Redis $r, string $address) {
        return jsonOrFalseFromRedis($r, "addr:" . $address);
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php
namespace App\MiniEntities;

class Name {
    // ...

    static function load(Redis $r, string $address) {
        return jsonOrFalseFromRedis($r, "addr:" . $address);
    }
}
```

They both use `jsonOrFalseFromRedis` function.

I know I can do a parent class and put the function there, however I want to keep it as normal function.

However I was not able to do so and at the moment I did yet another Java-like class with static method `jsonOrFalseFromRedis`.

## What I tried so far:

I did file called help.php and did `require_once "help.php";`, however it gives me following error:

```
Compile Error: Cannot redeclare App\MiniEntities\jsonOrFalseFromRedis() (previously declared in /www/sites/btc_pay/src/MiniEntities/help.php:9)
```

## Update

here is how I did it:

Name:

```
<?php
namespace App\MiniEntities;

class Name {
    // ...

    static function load(Redis $r, string $address) {
        return jsonOrFalseFromRedis($r, "addr:" . $address);
    }
}

require_once "help.php";
```

help.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\MiniEntities;


function jsonOrFalseFromRedis(Redis $r, $key) {
    $json = $r->get($key);

    if ($json)
        return json_decode($json, true);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How and where exactly did you declare the `jsonOrFalseFromRedis` function? At the function definition(s) to the question please. Did you try `return self::jsonOrFalseFromRedis();` ?

Comment: Are you talking about a regular "procedural" PHP function outside a class scope? Because Symfony is supposed to be used the OOP way.

Comment: yes. normal "free" / "procedural" function. The function do only one task, so no need to be a class. In Java, since there are no free functions it would be static method in some class. But in PHP we must not copy Java.

Comment: AFAIK this is bad practice in Symfony. You should be using static methods instead. Actually you shouldn't be using static methods either because it goes against the OOP pattern of using objects. Best would be to declare your helper classes as services and then inject them using DI. `require_once` should not be needed to use in a Symfony app.

Answer (score 1):

Using static methods or procedural functions is against the OOP pattern.

You should define the helper and your other classes as a service in your services.yml

```
App\MiniEntities\Helper:
    class: 'App\MiniEntities\Helper'

App\MiniEntities\Address:
    class: 'App\MiniEntities\Address'
    arguments: 
        $helper: '@App\MiniEntities\Helper'
```

Then inject your helper to the class using DI

```
class Address 
{
    private $helper;

    public function __construct(Helper $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }

    public function load(Redis $r, string $address) 
    {
        return $this->helper->jsonOrFalseFromRedis($r, "addr:" . $address);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way. However `jsonOrFalseFromRedis()` is complete "thing", it deals with single task and is encapsulated. It does not need any fancy "package" like class or something like this.

As I said before, because Java is limited (e.g. have no functions), Java programmer can not do it without wrapping in a class.

I don't know if Symfony is limited, but PHP definitely is not limited and can do it as C++ or Python.

Comment: Off course PHP is not limited in the way Java is and you are free to do as you like. I'm developing Symfony apps for quite a while now. Although it might seem too "fancy" to wrap a single function in a class, I feel it is always best to follow the intended patterns by Symfony. This will keep things straight and makes it easier to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called Helper and create static method inside that.

```
<?php
namespace App\MiniEntities;

class Helper {
    // ...

    static function jsonOrFalseFromRedis(Redis $r, string $address) {
        return 'code';
    }
}
```

and use

```
Helper::jsonOrFalseFromRedis($r, "addr:" . $address);
```

in your two classes.

Comment: this is exactly what I did. but is there any other way?

Comment: Best way to create a seperate class for Helper for common functions. You used static load in your code so in Helper also you need to use static function.

Comment: @Nick using static methods is agains the OOP pattern. See my answer